# Problem with xstring: IfEqCase case falls thru

Tags: xstring

In *Xfer* I read all chars of a string one by one, that are before a '\'.

*Trlt* 'translates' these chars and outputs them.

In the end the macros that ends the string are output.

**Problem**

If a '\' is encountered e.g. in '**xK\star**' or '**xK3\star**', the '**xK**' falls thru the IfEqCase test. Could it be a catcode problem? How to solve it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring,ifthen}

\renewcommand{\star}{{}\kern-0.1em\textbf{\large*}}

\def\GetTranslation#1{\textbf{#1}}

\def\Trlt#1{%
  \gdef\Rank{0}%
  \IfInteger{#1}%
  {#1\gdef\Rank{#1}}%
  {%
    \IfEqCase{#1}{%
      {K}{\GetTranslation{K}\gdef\Rank{1}}%
      {x}{x\gdef\Rank{0}}%
    }%[?#1?]% 'K' falls thru if followed by macro, why?
  }%
}% Trlt

\newcounter{ODwCnt}
\verbtocs{\bslash}|\|

\def\Xfer#1{%
  \begingroup%
    \fullexpandarg%
    \scancs[0]\mystring{#1}%
    \StrBefore{\mystring}{\bslash}[\Str]%
    \IfEq{\Str}{}{\def\Str{#1}}{}%
%    \IfEq{\Str}{}{\def\Str{#1}}{!\Str! }% Check \Str
    \setcounter{ODwCnt}{0}%
    \StrLen{\Str}[\Len]%
    \whiledo{\theODwCnt < \Len}{%
      \stepcounter{ODwCnt}%
      \StrChar{\Str}{\theODwCnt}[\OneChar]%
      \Trlt{\OneChar}%
    }%
    \StrBehind{\mystring}{\bslash}[\command]%
    \IfEq{\command}{}{}{%
      \tokenize\myCS{\bslash\command}%
      \myCS%
    }%
  \endgroup%
}% Xfer
\begin{document}

\Xfer{xK3\star}
\Xfer{xK3}

\end{document}
\endinput
```

Comment: It would be easier if you explained your aim.

Comment: I stripped it down as to have a MINIMAL example. Xfer gets called on columns of a table and Trlt does more than showed here, but that did not influence the behaviour. I NEED the translalation working properly on all chars even if there is a '\' afterwards. Hope this suffices, or should I post the entire code?

Comment: As far as I can see, you leave macros untouched and only “translate” characters. Is that the idea?

Comment: Yes, that is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your aim is to parse the input token by token, then a simpler approach will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\Xfer}{m}
 {
  \tl_map_function:nN { #1 } \jack_translate:n
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \jack_translate:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {K}{\textbf{K}}
    {x}{\textit{x}}
    {*}{\star}
   }
   { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\renewcommand{\star}{{}\kern-0.1em\textbf{\large*}}

\begin{document}

\Xfer{xK3\star}

\Xfer{xK3*}

\Xfer{xK3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The macro `\tl_map_function:nN` parses the argument token by token (but braced groups are treated as a unit) and passes the current one to the second macro, which can do the switch case work.

Comment: @Jack Remember that spaces between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` are ignored; if you need a space in the substitution text for a “translation“, use `~` for it.